# OrientDB Traverse SQL query efficiency

Tags: sql, select, graph-databases, orientdb

Apologies I am new to Graphing DB! I have the following basic structure in an [OrientDB](http://orientdb.com/):

[image]

I need to obtain all the `permission` associated with a given `User`. `permission` are always contained in a `Role` but a `Role` can belong either directly to a `User` or to a `Team`. I haven't added it to the image but the edges between `User > Role` and `Team > Role` are `has`. And between `User > Team` are `member`.

My current approach is:

```
SELECT permission FROM (
  TRAVERSE any() FROM #23:0 WHILE $depth <=4
) WHERE @class='Role'
```

However, I suspect that there is a much more efficient was of achieving this.

Comment: I would look into doing an sql-like union if it is possible in orientdb... That should be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `any()` for traversal, you can use named edges.

Eg. if `user -belongsTo-> team` and `user,team -hasPermission-> permission` you can write this query like

```
SELECT FROM (
   TRAVERSE out('belongsTo', 'hasPermission') FROM #23:0 WHILE $depth <=2
) WHERE @class='Role'
```

This will avoid traversal of unwanted branches.

Comment: Like it. Is there a performance penalty for using `$depth <=2`?

Comment: no, there is no performance penalty. Moreover, in v 2.1 you can also use MAXDEPTH, that is even more efficient, eg `TRAVERSE out('belongsTo', 'hasPermission') FROM #23:0 maxdepth 2`